# Json serialization error when updating user in Azure AD via GRAPH

Tags: c#, json.net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft.Graph library [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) to update a user in Azure AD. This works for some users, but fails for others. My code looks like this:

```
public async Task<User> UpdateUser(AdUser adUser)
{
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_azureAuthenticationProvider);

    var user = await GetUser(adUser.UserPrincipalName);

    user.GivenName = adUser.GivenName;
    user.Surname = adUser.LastName;
    user.DisplayName = adUser.DisplayName;
    user.Department = adUser.Department;
    user.AccountEnabled = adUser.AccountEnabled;

    await graphServiceClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
    await UpdateUserGroups(adUser);

    return await GetUser(adUser.UserPrincipalName);
}
```

The AdUser class is fairly basic and just includes the properties to update:

```
public class AdUser
{
    public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public List<string> OldGroups { get; set; }
    public List<string> OldRoles { get; set; }
    public List<string> NewGroups { get; set; }
    public List<string> NewRoles { get; set; }
    public bool AccountEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn { get; set; }
}
```

For the first three users to be updated, this works just fine. On the fourth user, I get a generic AggregateException with the message, "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' was thrown."

Firing up Fiddler shows the failed request:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Can not add property department to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b82c4098-6031-40c4-ac6a-4f43746e7b48",
      "date": "2016-07-12T05:55:08"
    }
  }
}
```

If I step through the code, I can see the error occurs on this line:

```
await graphServiceClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

This always occurs for the same user. Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

**Update 1:**
For completeness, my GetUser method looks like this:

```
public const string AdUserFields = "UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,GivenName,Surname,Department,MemberOf,AccountEnabled";

public async Task<User> GetUser(string userPrincipalName, string fields = AdUserFields)
{
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_azureAuthenticationProvider);

    var user = await graphServiceClient.Users[userPrincipalName].Request().Select(fields).GetAsync();

    return user;
}
```

**Update 2:**
The request and response looks like this. Note that I did not construct the JSON, the SDK does that for me. I am aware of the duplicate key in the request:

*REQUEST:*

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jane.doe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com HTTP/1.1
SdkVersion: graph-dotnet-1.0.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 478
Expect: 100-continue

{"accountEnabled":true,"businessPhones":[],"department":"department","displayName":"Jane Doe (department)","givenName":"Jane","surname":"Doe","userPrincipalName":"jane.doe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com","id":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity","givenName":null,"jobTitle":null,"mail":null,"mobilePhone":null,"officeLocation":null,"preferredLanguage":null,"surname":null}
```

*RESPONSE:*

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: 2c0437b3-2438-4a34-bf70-937bec2143d1
client-request-id: 2c0437b3-2438-4a34-bf70-937bec2143d1
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"SouthEast Asia","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_0","ADSiteName":"SIN"}}
Duration: 30.6384
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 03:08:14 GMT

142
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Can not add property givenName to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2c0437b3-2438-4a34-bf70-937bec2143d1",
      "date": "2016-07-13T03:08:14"
    }
  }
}
0
```

Comment: What's the exact body data for the REST request?

Comment: I've added the request and response in update 2 above. Thanks!

Comment: I've also logged an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tracked this down to a bug in the way we are de-serializing the JSON data into their respective models. The model properties are attributed with standard .NET data contracts. However, we use NewtonSoft to do the actual JSON work. The combination of the two causes null values for properties to be incorrectly placed into the AdditionalData dictionary property (a "catch-all" bucket for unknown values).

A fix for this issue will be released with the next SDK update. You can track it [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/28) moving forward.

To workaround the issue for the short-term, you can iterate through the AdditionalData dictionary and remove any entry where the key matches a known property on the model. If you do this before sending the update, it should work correctly.

**More Detail**

It is possible to reproduce this bug generically outside our SDK. For example:

```
<!-- language: c# -->

public class User
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, IsRequired = false, Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, IsRequired = false, Name = "department")]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData(ReadData = true, WriteData = true)]
    public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalData { get; set; }
}

void SomeFunction()
{
    string json = @"{ 'name': 'Bob Smith', 'department': null }";
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);

    // Inspecting user here will show the Name property with the correct
    // value, the Department property with a null value, but will also
    // have a "department = null" key / value pair incorrectly in the
    // AdditionalData property.
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for working on this for me! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The json data in you request is invalidate, it added duplicate property, **givenName** and  **surname** like figure below:

[image]
Please remove the duplicate one and ensure the json data is validate you can check it from [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

And to update the user, we only need to provide the changed field we wanted. For example, here is sample that update the department for the user for your reference:

```
 var user = graphserviceClient.Me.Request();
 var newUser = new User();
 newUser.Department = "dep1";
 var updateUser=await user.UpdateAsync(newUser);
```

Comment: I realise there is a duplicate key, but I am using the GRAPH SDK from nuget. I am not constructing the JSON, the SDK is doing it